# Why does my Component not update after posting data to REST service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I am trying to build my first react.js app and am wondering, why my page does neither update after POSTING a new player to my app via axios, nor after DELETING one. As I refresh the page afterwards the players are created or gone depending on the operation. So the API part is working just fine.

I have a PlayerPage.js like so:

*PlayerPage.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlayerForm from './playerform';
import PlayCard from './playercard';

class PlayerPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    players: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/player')
      .then(res => {
        const players = res.data;
        this.setState({ players });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Add Player</h2>
        <PlayerForm />
        <hr></hr>
        <h2>Available Player</h2>
        {this.state.players.map(player => (
          <PlayCard player={player} key={player.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerPage;
```

It does reference (and fill in from API) the PlayerForm and PlayerCard component, which look like this:

*playerform.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  Form,
  Button
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class PlayerForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    nickname: ''
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/player', JSON.stringify(this.state), {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then()
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handelChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter player name"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Nickname</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="nickname"
            placeholder="Enter player nickname"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button variant="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          Add
        </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerForm;
```

and *playercard.js*:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

class PlayerCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.player = props.player;

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:3001/player/${this.player.id}`)
      .then()
      .catch(console.log);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="flex-row flex-wrap">
        <Card.Header>
          <Card.Img variant="left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body variant="center">
          <Card.Title>{this.player.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle>{this.player.nickname}</Card.Subtitle>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Body variant="right">
          <Button variant="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

PlayerCard.propTypes = {
  player: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default PlayerCard;
```

So the question is, why does my side not update properly?
I am grateful for any hints. Thanks in advance.

**Bonus question**: How do I fetch the ip and port dynamically depending on where the node server is running?

Comment: you need to call the `GET` method on `PlayerPage.js` again for fetching the updated list of players after creating or deleting the player in order to update the state of the component.

Comment: You are not updating state in both scenarios. You have to update state and remove the deleted player form the state and add new player in state on save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all suggested, you are not updating the state of the `PlayerPage` component. Even though answer suggested by [@tristan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59713114/2334849) works, I would suggest to reduce API calls as much as possible. My solution would be as following:

*PlayerPage.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlayerForm from './playerform';
import PlayCard from './playercard';

class PlayerPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    players: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/player')
      .then(res => {
        const players = res.data;
        this.setState({ players });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  handleAddNewPlayer = player => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      players: [...prevState.players, player] // or [player, ...prevState.players]
    }))
  }

  handleRemovePlayer = id => {
    const players = this.state.filter(player => player.id !== id)
    this.setState({ players })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Add Player</h2>
        <PlayerForm handleAddNewPlayer={this.handleAddNewPlayer}/>
        <hr></hr>
        <h2>Available Player</h2>
        {this.state.players.map(player => (
          <PlayCard player={player} key={player.id} handleRemovePlayer={this.handleRemovePlayer} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PlayerPage;
```

*playerform.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  Form,
  Button
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class PlayerForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    nickname: ''
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/player', JSON.stringify(this.state), {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.props.handleAddNewPlayer(data)) // adjust this api call to return added user with id
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handelChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter player name"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Nickname</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="nickname"
            placeholder="Enter player nickname"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button variant="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          Add
        </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerForm;
```

and *playercard.js*:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

class PlayerCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.player = props.player;

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:3001/player/${this.player.id}`)
      .then(this.props.handleRemovePlayer(this.player.id))
      .catch(console.log);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="flex-row flex-wrap">
        <Card.Header>
          <Card.Img variant="left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body variant="center">
          <Card.Title>{this.player.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle>{this.player.nickname}</Card.Subtitle>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Body variant="right">
          <Button variant="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

PlayerCard.propTypes = {
  player: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default PlayerCard;
```

Comment: This is indeed the best solution maintaining the state properly. Nice, thanks. Only after adding a player the image is not shown properly (image functionality is now added on to the source code)

Comment: You want to upload image for each player?

Comment: Yes I do. This is now working for me. Migrating to redux right now though.

Answer (score 4):

**Why it's not working:**

Because you are not refreshing the list view when the form is submitted.
React is not magic, you need to tell when you want the view to be rerender.

One way to to this is adding a `onCreate` prop to your `playerform.js` and run the function when the form is successfully submitted.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlayerForm from './playerform';
import PlayCard from './playercard';

class PlayerPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    players: []
  };

  loadPlayers() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/player')
      .then(res => {
        const players = res.data;
        this.setState({ players });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPlayers();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Add Player</h2>
        <PlayerForm onCreate={() => this.loadPlayers()}/>
        <hr></hr>
        <h2>Available Player</h2>
        {this.state.players.map(player => (
          <PlayCard player={player} key={player.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerPage;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  Form,
  Button
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class PlayerForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    nickname: ''
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3001/player', JSON.stringify(this.state), {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.onCreate();
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handelChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter player name"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormLabel>Nickname</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            name="nickname"
            placeholder="Enter player nickname"
            onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button variant="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          Add
        </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerForm;
```

I didn't check if the prop is present but normally you should.

**How to handle API route**

You should use environments variables:

`.env`

```
API_HOST=http://localhost:3001/
```

```
process.env.API_HOST
```

But it's depending on your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle method `componentDidMount()` doesn't run in `PlayerPage.js` every time the state changes, just once when it first loads onto the page. This means the GET request is only run once when the page loads.

You need to either call the GET route again after a POST or DELETE happens, or update the app's state with the data from the POST/DELETE call when it happens to put that data onto the page as well as into the database.

Comment: So my feeling says that updating the state might be the better thing to do as there is no additional GET call to the API then. So how would I maintaine the state? Does my POST and DELETE need to return the players list in the response then and I do setState to the response then?

Answer (score 0):

To update the PlayerCard list, the players state must be updated in PlayerPage.

Since the parent has no way to get new players after the Rest API call, it seems that we need a callback function to update the parent component as a child.

Comment: Please elaborate on the callback function a little more. This sounds exactly like a thing I want to have. I am also planning on using redux on another state of the app later on. Do you think using redux here might make any sense already?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using any state management tool(Redux, Flux), and only react is in place and also you don't want to call the api again.
Inside PlayerPage component make a function

```
addPlayer=(player)=>{
this.setState({
players: {...players, player}
})
}
}
```

and in render of the same component

Inside PlayerCard

```
handleClick() {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:3001/player/${this.player.id}`)
      .then((response)=>{
you get your output pass it to props
var player=response.data
this.props.addPlayer(response)
    })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
```

This example is only with reference to the addPlayer . You can customise it according to your requirement